# How to create bitmap from String text inside a circle using canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I want to get user initials, to set on an ImageView a bitmap with one or two characteres, inside a circle, like that:

[image]

I've tried some ways to draw a circle and a text in canvas, but it doesn't work properly. How can I do that?

Comment: its very simple, try to use <shape> to draw circle and set that as your textview background. is there any specific reason for choosing imageview ??

Comment: @Madhu It's because if the user has a picture url, I have to show it, otherwise I have to show the initials like that.

Comment: you can check internally right, if user returns url then show the imageview otherwise you cna show the textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the TextDrawable library, and found it to be very useful.
This light-weight library provides images with letter/text like the Gmail app. It extends the Drawable class thus can be used with existing/custom/network ImageView classes. Also included is a fluent interface for creating drawables and a customizable ColorGenerator.

[Click here for example on github](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable)

Comment: You should write some words about the library.

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
public Bitmap createImage(int width, int height, int color, String name) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRect(0F, 0F, (float) width, (float) height, paint2);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(72);
        paint.setTextScaleX(1);
        canvas.drawText(name, 75 - 25, 75 + 20, paint);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Image View to Set Circle ImageView

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageHelper.createImageRounded(getApplicationContext(), 150, 150, "S"));
```

Create Method for Round Image using Canvas

```
public static Bitmap createImageRounded(Context context, int width, int height, String name)
{
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    Paint paintCicle = new Paint();
    Paint paintText = new Paint();

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float roundPx = 100*density;

    paintCicle.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    paintCicle.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

// Set Border For Circle
    paintCicle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintCicle.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);

    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paintCicle);

    paintText.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    paintText.setTextSize(72);

    canvas.drawText(name, 75 - 23, 75 + 25, paintText);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: what is this logic 75 - 23, 75 + 25 can u plz explain